# Getting the error while viewing the order in admin Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean

Tags: orders, magento-1, payment, fatal-error, view

I am getting the below error while opening/viewing admin -> sales -> order -> view.

> Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in
>   /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line
>   46

This error is causing for orders, those are having the order total is Zero means No Payment Information Required.

We are using Magento ver. 1.13.1.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you done any customization for payments or add any custom extension for the payment or shipping methods?

Comment: @ Abdul thanks for reply, We have not done any customization or modifications related to payment gateway.

Comment: have you added any  custom extention?

Comment: Yes we have added one extra column to sales order grid.

Comment: Pls comment your code and check again. I think working :)

Comment: Yes, if i remove that it is working, but the column is necessary for me, can you tell me how can i debug.

Comment: can you share you custom code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50300/discussion-between-krishna-ijjada-at-i95dev-and-abdul).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code

**From**

```
protected function _prepareCollection() 
{ 

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass()); 

$collection->getSelect()->join(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=billing.parent_id and billing.address_type="billing"',array('*')); 


$this->setCollection($collection); 
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection(); 


}
```

**To**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id' ,array('company'=> 'company'));
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('sales_flat_order_address.address_type', array('eq' => 'billing'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Comment: @Abdul It will be greate if you can explain about the fix